# Does Ubuntu for phones support the AMR-WB codec, aka HD Voice?

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, modem, codecs

Normally the phone frequency is limited, ranging from 300 Hz to 3,4 kHz.
Using the AMR-WB codec, speech is transmitted from 80 Hz to 7 kHz.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wideband_audio

If Ubuntu uses the android GSM/UMTS/LTE driver from android (and the driver supports the codec), does wideband audio work in Ubuntu's phone app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just searched the entire source repository for Ubuntu Touch for "AMR" and there is nothing in there that suggests AMR-WB is used, so the simple answer to your question is: **No**.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news…*

Comment: Thanks, great idea. I'd like to file a bug report about the issue. In your opinion, what is the correct package to file the report?

Comment: The package exists, so it just needs to be included in Ubuntu touch: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libopencore-amrwb-dev

Comment: Also: you've still got 6 days...  Maybe a developer will walk in, see your question and do it for you...  You shouldn't accept my answer (yet)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

HD voice aka wideband audio works.
Confirmed with a Meizu MX4.